# Remote commands via ssh fail, even though ssh -T git@github.com is successful

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I've followed [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) guide in order to generate a key, and I've correctly added it to my SSH identities

```
PS C:\Users\gianm\.ssh> ssh-add myGithub
Identity added: myGithub (*email_Address_I_Use_On_Github*)
```

I've also added the corresponding public key to my Github account and it seems like I can actually successfully establish a connection.

```
PS C:\Users\gianm> ssh -T git@github.com
Hi *my_Username*! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I've then added a remote origin to a local git repository.

```
PS C:\Users\gianm\project> git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:*my_Username*/*existing_Github_Repository*.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:*my_Username*/*existing_Github_Repository*.git (push)
```

But if I try doing something like git push, this is what happens.

```
PS C:\Users\gianm\project> git push -u origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As it might appear obvious by now, I'm on Windows, running this specific version of git: `git version 2.31.1.windows.1`.

Comment: Git-for-Windows has its own ssh, separate from the Windows system ssh, for reasons I don't understand (I don't use Windows so these reasons probably exist, I just don't know them). As such it's likely that the Git ssh is using a different method to find and present the public key. You can configure Git to use a particular ssh, using either `core.sshCommand` (`git config`) or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (environment) to invoke a specific ssh version, which might help.

Comment: As I know, git-for-windows has `git-bash.exe` and `bash.exe`. They have their own home directories. `git-bash` uses `/c/Users/Username` and `bash` uses `/h/` on my computer. `ssh` and `git push` may read ssh keys from different `.ssh` folders. `.ssh` is usually under the home directory.

Comment: @torek This did the trick! I've first ran `which ssh` to find the directory of windows' ssh command, and then I've added it to the enviroment variables as `GIT_SSH` (not `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`).  Thank you very much, I can't tell how many hours I've spent yesterday looking for a way to fix this.
PS: The reason why git comes with its own ssh commands is probably that older windows versions didn't came with openssh bundled in.

Comment: The [top level Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) describes both env variables and says that `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence. I'm not sure if there is any convention here on which one to use: if you're pointing directly at a binary, either one should work. See also the descriptions of `GIT_SSH_VARIANT` and `ssh.variant`.

Comment: @torek that might be it, I didn't refer specifically to ssh.exe, just to the directory where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't refer specifically to ssh.exe, just to the directory where it is located.

I confirm you need to include the exe in those variables.

For instance:

```
 set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv"
```

Then a `git push` will show you *where* `ssh.exe` is looking for your keys: you can then make sure that path includes your `id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub` you defined initially.