# I can authenticate to Github using SSH but I get a permission denied when trying to push to my repo

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am new to using Git and SSH authentication so bear with me.

I set up my repo on github and was pushing to it just fine using username and password. But then I saw that github is deprecating that so I decided to use SSH instead. I found a tutorial on how to create SSH keys and add them to github. I think I must have doe that right because I do the authentication test with github:

`ssh -T git@github.com`

And I get:

`Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

But then I run:

`git push origin`

and I get:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I would really appreciate any help because this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Probably `origin` is a repo which your key does not have write access to?

Comment: If you are on Windows, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67273366/1256452).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `git remote -v` shows you an SSH URL to a repository you have access to (that you have created for instance), try (assuming Linux):

```
 GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git push
```

On Windows, in a CMD:

```
 set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v"
 git push
```

You will see where Git is looking for SSH keys, and what URL it uses.

It should be: `git@github.com:<you>/<yourRepo>`

Comment: I am using windows, is there something similar?

Comment: @J-Rome I have edited the answer to add the Windows version of that command.